# Is there a method that is only called once during the time the app is open in Dart/ Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

`initState` seems to be called every time the screen it belongs to is shown. Is there a method that is called only once during the time the app is open?

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: @RoyalGriffin I'm trying to use the firebase_admob plugin to show banner ads at the bottom of the screen. My code basically looks like [this](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_admob/example/lib/main.dart) except instead of using buttons to load and show the banner I would like to load and show the banner when the app is launched. The problem is if I put the code to load and show the banner in `initState` it will be called every time the main screen is shown which causes the ad to change every time the main screen is shown which is not ideal.

Comment: The `main()` function?

Comment: @solarc Thanks that is what I was looking for. Kind of obvious, my mistake.

Comment: You should probably use a boolean in `SharedPreferences` to perform something just once.